# Regex/Method to remove namespace from a Type.FullName - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am working on writing a method to remove the namespace from a System.Type.FullName (not XML).

I started off googling and didn't get too far so switched to trying to write a Regex I could use with a Regex.Replace().  But I am far from a master of the Regex arts, so I present myself humbly before the regex gods.

Given the following inputs:

```
name.space.class
name.space.class<other.name.space.class1>
name.space.class<other.name.space.class1, shortSpace.class2>
```

I need to remove the namespaces so I get:

```
class
class<class1>
class<class1, class2>
```

Alternatively, if anyone knows of an existing library that has this functionality, all the better!

**Note:** I know System.Type has a Namespace property that I could use to remove the namespace (ie System.Type.FullName - System.Type.Namespace), but my method takes a type name as a string and needs to work with type names that the run-time does not know about (can't resolve).

Comment: What if this happens `Ns.Class<Ns1.Class1<ns2.Class3, ns3.Class4>>` ??

Comment: Result should be class<class1<class3,class4>>.  -- Good question!

Comment: What about `Ns1.Class<Ns2.Class, Ns3.Class>`? Your intended result of `Class<Class, Class>` is clearly incorrect. Namespaces matter.

Comment: Also there is an issue with nested classes `Class1.NestedClass<Ns.Class2>`!!

Comment: @allonguralnek I agree Namespaces do matter, but for this case I need to remove them all, I'm not concerned if the generic type parameters are in a different namespace.

Comment: @ahmedKRAIEM - you're not making my life any easier, but certainly making my code more complete :).  In the case of nested classes, they will either come in as Class+NestedClass (instead of class.nestedclass).  Otherwise, I don't think I'm going to worry about this case, there would be no way of knowing if the class is nested from just a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this...

```
[.\w]+\.(\w+)
```

...and substiuting with `$1`. See it in action on [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/rN7tE6).

From looking at some C# examples it seems you would do

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[.\w]+\.(\w+)", "$1");
```

Comment: That looks promising!  Give me a second to throw it into a test.

Comment: How do I add a 'substring' using the C# Regex class?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean...? Where and why do you want to add a substring?

Comment: From looking at some C# examples it seems you would do `string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[.\w]+\.(\w+)", "$1");`

Comment: Sorry, I meant substituting, but I got it: `new Regex(@"[.\w]+\.(\w+)").Replace("name.space.class", "$1");`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static string RemoveNamespaces(string typename)
{
    return string.Join("", 
          Regex.Split(typename, 
                     @"([^\w\.])").Select(p => 
                                     p.Substring(p.LastIndexOf('.') + 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even consider using regexes for this. Imperative code is pretty trivial here, although it requires a bit of string-fu:

```
public string RemoveNamespace(string typename)
{
    if(typename.Contains("<")
    {            
        var genericArguments = 
            typename.
                // in reality, we need a substring before 
                // first occurence of "<" and last occurence of ">"
                SubstringBetween("<", ">").
                Split(',').
                Select(string.Trim).
                Select(RemoveNamespace);

        return 
            RemoveNamespace(typename.SubstringBefore("<")) + 
                "<" + 
                string.Join(", ", genericArguments) + 
                ">";
    }
    else
    {
        return typename.Trim().SubstringAfterLastOccurenceOf(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but won't work in all cases (nested generic parameters).

Comment: .. And then splits _all_ the substring (wich may contain other nested parameters in other "<" and ">" ) so `class<class<ns1.class, class>>` results in: `substring[0] = "class<ns1.class"` and `substring[1] = "class"` and `substring[0]` doesn't have a `SubstringBetween("<", ">")`.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good situation to use positive lookahead:

```
(\w+[.+])+(?=\w+)
```

This pattern will match any number of words separated by periods or plusses, except the last one in a sequence (the short name of the type). Replacing the matches by the empty string will remove all namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not split by dot(.) and take only the last string

Comment: I had tried that approach, unfortunately when I had a generic (ie n.s.c<n.s.c1, s.c2> I would end up with .c2> instead of c<c1, c2>

Comment: split by < and you will get 2 strings, A and B, you split A by dot and take the last string call it A1. Split B after , and then split the resulting strings by dot, and again get only the last string resulting in B1,...Bn, the result is A1+"<"+B1+","+...+Bn+">"